# Unable to change Plugin and Custom Workflow Activity Tracing setting in Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm simply trying to enable tracing in System Settings -> Customization tab and the OK button does not work. There is a JavaScript error which say: "Object doesn't support property or method 'down'"

Has anybody encountered that and have possible workaround to this. I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise
[image]

Comment: Since you are on IE, did you double check to see if you are on the latest "Document Mode"? (Emulation Tab on developer tools), also does it happen on other browsers like chrome? I just tested and works fine for me, so it does make me wonder if your IE is running in a lower document mode than usual (8 or 7) or if your site has been added to compatibility mode list of sites.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 

In IE, it has Edge mode by default. I tried on 10 as well and on Chrome too. The version on IE is 11.0.9600.18427.

Comment: Could you paste whole button tag from DOM Explorer?

Comment: Sure, here's the OK button tag.

`<button title="OK" class="ms-crm-RefreshDialog-Button" id="butBegin" style="margin-left: 8px;" onkeydown="" onclick="if(!Mscrm.Utilities.resetValidationFailedElement()){applychanges();}" type="button">OK</button>`